# How to embed Google maps locations in an iframe

Tags: google-maps

I have a custom set of locations on Google maps, at https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zzX-BuFGi82s.kBQeXTGL4SqY . When I try to embed this in an iframe, I get the following console error:

> Refused to display '[URL]' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) explains what's happening, and Q Studio's answer says  adding &output=embed to a Google Maps link generally solves it. But it doesn't with the above URL, presumably because it's at mapsengine.google.com rather than maps.google.com. How can I make this work? I can get admin access to the original map's location dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the answer was to use this form of URL: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zzX-BuFGi82s.kBQeXTGL4SqY

Comment: This worked for me!. How did you know to use this format and why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the API. You can use the Maps Engine API https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/

It seems like some Maps Engine API functions cost money though.

If the locations are real you can use the Maps API.